# How to mount the newly created linux partitions?

Tags: partitioning, mount, ownership

It seems repetitive even to myself asking this but I've searched this forum and have not been able to fix my issue. I had created one extended partition and installed my UBUNTU 14.04 on it.

Now I have 440 GB available so have recently created two new primary partitions on the free space. But when I click them to mount and access them from the "Places" menu (I have installed Ubuntu-mate) the only thing there I would have is a window opened and I can not create anything on it.

I figured it may have been mounted as root and I have not a single clue how to change it to my username. Could you please  help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as I suppose by mounting your partition read only, so either you have to remount with write permissions or add to fstab to automount automatically.

#### Get the UUID

Run the command:

```
sudo blkid
```

Then open /etc/fstab:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Now  add the line to the bottom of /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=UUID /mounting-point ext4 defaults  0      2
```

Replace UUID with result of your UUID of /dev/sdX

Replace /mounting-point with path to mount the partition on

Replace ext4 with your partition filesystem type

Comment: @Maytux : thank you very much for posting the answer to me. I am going to check it right now. I have also found an other way which I started to describe right after your answer. I wish you the best and, thank you very much again.

Comment: You are welcome and your answer is good +1)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, This can be the solution:
1- Type the "`lsblk`" command to see the drives that are seen by your distribution and decide which one you want to mount (in my case it was /dev/sda3) and where you want to set to be its mount point (I chose it to be /mnt/EXTRA_I).
2-use the `mount` command using `sudo` like this:
`sudo mount -Rc /dev/sda3/ /mnt/EXTRAS_I
(you can learn more about the commands above by typing the command name first, and a --help after it. example:`mount --help`)
3-Now type your password as you've been asked to do so.
4-Type lsblk again, and observe that your drive chosen is mounted (one of the fields below "MOUNTPOINT" now contains a strins value. in my case: /mnt/EXTRAS_II).
5-it is time to change the owner from "root" to your own. It was "koorosh" in my case. Example: sudo chown -Rc koorosh:koorosh /mnt/EXTRAS_I
6-Observe the prompts of output that declares the mount point is now yours.
7-Congradulations, You have succeeded, and the next time you want to mount the drive (in my case: EXTRAS_I) and view the contents of it, you will have to just double-click on its name in your file manager.

`lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   2.8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 210.9G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 219.5G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.5G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0  25.1G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom`


`sudo mount /dev/sda3/ /mnt/EXTRAS_I
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   2.8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 210.9G  0 part /mnt/EXTRAS_I
├─sda4   8:4    0 219.5G  0 part

├─sda5   8:5    0   7.5G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0  25.1G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom`


`sudo chown -Rc cockroach:cockroach /mnt/EXTRAS_I
changed ownership of /mnt/EXTRAS_II/lost+found’ from root:root to cockroach:cockroach
changed ownership of /mnt/EXTRAS_II’ from root:root to cockroach:cockroach`


`sudo umount /dev/sda3`

Comment: If there is already ext-formatted data on that partition, this method is going to wipe ALL of the permissions on those files. This is a nuclear option. ONLY use it if you don't have any data (read: an OS!) on that partition.